# Does having my flag declined affect my account adversely?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I had a flag declined and it made me wonder what if any negative impacts result from my flags being declined?

I don't want to create "flag bloat" and I am a lot more careful about flagging posts now when they might not necessarily need to be.  Still I am curious if declines flags shine badly on my own participation.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, no. A declined flag will have absolutely no affect whatsoever on your account.

Previously, flag weight used to exist, which was a number that somewhat represented your history of flagging based on helpful and declined flags. That feature also allowed a user to fall into a "flag hellban" which basically permanently blocked a user from further flagging activity. Flag weight has since been removed from all flagging features in favor of a simple "helpful flags" count. The number is kept in the backend, but not used for any purposes anymore.

**However**, if you consistently cast a *lot* of flags that end up declined and a moderator notices the behavior, you *can* receive an account suspension for it. That would take a lot of effort in poor flagging habits, and isn't something you should be worried about if you just have a decline here and there.